# Using data in Gatsby to dynamically render information

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, gatsby

I am new to Gatsby and have run into a bit of a snag. I have an EventsContainer that contains an UpcomingEvent component. I am trying to render the particular data that goes with the UpcomingEvent when the upcomingEvent is set to true and only when it is set to true. I was able to get my EventCard working with the data by using a map, but I cannot use map in the same way for the UpcomingEvent, and I feel like I have tried everything I can think of.

Here is my EventsContainer component:

```
import React from 'react'

import { Grid } from '@material-ui/core'

import EventCard from './components/EventCard'
import UpcomingEvent from './components/UpcomingEvent'

import useStyles from './styles'

const EventsContainer = ({ events }) => {
  const classes = useStyles()

  return (
    <div>
      {/*-------------Mobile View-------------- */}
      <div className={classes.allContainerMobile}>
        <section className={classes.headingContainerMobile}>
          <p className={classes.allEventsTitleMobile}>ALL EVENTS</p>

          <div className={classes.parentDivImageMobile}>
            <div className={classes.ImageDivMobile}>
              <img
                src={EventsHeroImageMobile}
                className={classes.heroImageMobile}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>

        <section>
          <p
            className={
              UpcomingEvent
                ? classes.upcomingShowMobileUpcomingEvent
                : classes.upcomingShowMobile
            }
          >
            UPCOMING SHOW
          </p>

          {!UpcomingEvent ? (
            <p className={classes.noUpcomingShowsMobile}>
              NO UPCOMING SHOWS...FOR NOW.
            </p>
          ) : (
            <div className={classes.flyerImageMobile}>
              <div className={classes.upcomingShowParentMobile}>
                <img
                  src={UpcomingShowFlyerMobile}
                  className={classes.imageStyleMobile}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
        </section>

        {UpcomingEvent && (
          <UpcomingEvent
            name={UpcomingEvent.name}
            day={UpcomingEvent.day}
            month={UpcomingEvent.month}
            time={UpcomingEvent.time}
            location={UpcomingEvent.location}
            description={UpcomingEvent.description}
          />
        )}

        <section>
          <h2
            className={
              UpcomingEvent
                ? classes.pastShowsUpcomingMobile
                : classes.pastShowsMobile
            }
          >
            PAST SHOWS
          </h2>

          <div className={classes.eventsCardMobile}>
            {events.map(({ node }, i) => {
              if (node.upcomingEvent) return

              return (
                <EventCard
                  key={`${node.title}-${i}`}
                  name={node.name}
                  month={node.month}
                  day={node.day}
                  title={node.title}
                  time={node.time}
                  location={node.location}
                />
              )
            })}
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>

      {/* -----------Desktop View --------------- */}
      <div className={classes.containerDesktop}>
        <div className={classes.headingContainerDesktop}>
          <Grid
            container
            direction='row'
            className={classes.gridContainerDesktop}
          >
            <Grid item md={6} lg={6}>
              <div className={classes.allEventsContainerDesktop}>
                <p className={classes.allEventsTitleDesktop}>ALL EVENTS</p>
              </div>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item md={6} lg={6} className={classes.countdownGridContainer}>
              <div>
                <div className={classes.parentDivImageDesktop}>
                  <div className={classes.ImageDivDesktop}>
                    <img
                      src={EventsHeroImage}
                      className={classes.placeHolderImageDesktop}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p className={classes.upcomingShowDesktop}>UPCOMING SHOW</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          {!UpcomingEvent ? (
            <p className={classes.noUpcomingShowsDesktop}>
              NO UPCOMING SHOWS...FOR NOW.
            </p>
          ) : (
            <div>
              <UpcomingEvent
                name={UpcomingEvent.name}
                day={UpcomingEvent.day}
                month={UpcomingEvent.month}
                time={UpcomingEvent.time}
                location={UpcomingEvent.location}
                description={UpcomingEvent.description}
              />
            </div>
          )}
          <h2 className={classes.pastShowsDesktop}>PAST SHOWS</h2>
        </div>
        <div className={classes.eventsCardDesktop}>
          {events.map(({ node }, i) => {
            if (node.upcomingEvent) return

            return (
              <EventCard
                key={`${node.title}-${i}`}
                name={node.name}
                month={node.month}
                day={node.day}
                title={node.title}
                time={node.time}
                location={node.location}
              />
            )
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default EventsContainer
```

Here is my UpcomingEvent component:

```
import React from 'react'

import { Grid, Button } from '@material-ui/core'

import UpcomingShowFlyerDesktop from 'images/events/flyers/flyer-desktop.png'
import useStyles from '../../styles'

const UpcomingEvent = ({ name, description, month, day, location }) => {
  const classes = useStyles()

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <div className={classes.upcomingShowsMobile}>
          <div className={classes.titleContainerMobile}>
            <p className={classes.upcomingShowTitleMobile}>{name}</p>
          </div>
          <div className={classes.dateLocationContainerMobile}>
            <p className={classes.upcomingShowDateLocationMobile}>
              {month} {day} |{location}
            </p>
          </div>
          <div className={classes.aboutContainerMobile}>
            <p className={classes.aboutUpcomingShowMobile}>{description}</p>
          </div>
          <div className={classes.upcomingShowButtonContainerMobile}>
            <Button className={classes.upcomingShowButtonMobile}>
              BUY TICKETS
            </Button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      {/* ///////// Desktop View //////////////// */}
      <div>
        <Grid
          container
          direction='row'
          spacing={0}
          className={classes.imageGridContainer}
        >
          <Grid item md={6} lg={6}>
            <div className={classes.imageContainerDesktop}>
              <div className={classes.imageParentDesktop}>
                <img
                  className={classes.upcomingShowFlyerDesktop}
                  src={UpcomingShowFlyerDesktop}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </Grid>
          <Grid
            item
            md={6}
            lg={6}
            className={classes.informationContainerDesktop}
          >
            <div className={classes.upcomingShowsDesktop}>
              <div className={classes.titleContainerDesktop}>
                <p className={classes.upcomingShowTitleDesktop}>{name}</p>
              </div>
              <div className={classes.dateLocationContainer}>
                <p className={classes.upcomingShowDateLocationDesktop}>
                  {month} {day} | {location}
                </p>
              </div>
              <div className={classes.aboutContainerDesktop}>
                <p className={classes.aboutUpcomingShowDesktop}>
                  {description}
                </p>
              </div>
              <div className={classes.upcomingShowButtonContainerDesktop}>
                <Button className={classes.upcomingShowButtonDesktop}>
                  BUY TICKETS
                </Button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default UpcomingEvent
```

And, here is my pages/events.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import { graphql } from 'gatsby'

import GlobalProvider from 'components/GlobalProvider'
import EventsContainer from 'containers/EventsContainer'

const Events = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <GlobalProvider>
      <EventsContainer events={data.allEventsJson.edges}></EventsContainer>
    </GlobalProvider>
  )
}
export const query = graphql`
  query {
    allEventsJson {
      edges {
        node {
          month
          day
          name
          time
          location
          upcomingEvent
        }
      }
    }
  }
`

export default Events
```

Any help or further understanding anyone could provide would be incredibly helpful and greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue I was having, I created a variable that contained the mapped information for upcomingEvent. Then I called on the variable in the section the upcomingEvent was to be displayed in:

```
import React from 'react'

import { Grid } from '@material-ui/core'

import EventCard from './components/EventCard'
import UpcomingEvent from './components/UpcomingEvent'

import useStyles from './styles'

const EventsContainer = ({ events }) => {
  // console.log(events)
  const classes = useStyles()
  const [upcomingEvent, setUpcomingEvent] = React.useState(false)

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const isThereUpcomingEvent = events.some(({ node }) => {
      return !!node.upcomingEvent
    })

    if (isThereUpcomingEvent) {
      setUpcomingEvent(true)
    } else {
      setUpcomingEvent(false)
    }
  }, [])

  console.log(upcomingEvent)

  const upcoming = events.map(({ node }) => {
    if (node.upcomingEvent) {
      return (
        <UpcomingEvent
          name={node.name}
          day={node.day}
          month={node.month}
          time={node.time}
          location={node.location}
          description={node.description}
        />
      )
    }
  })

  return (
    <div>
      {/*-------------Mobile View-------------- */}
      <div className={classes.allContainerMobile}>
        <section className={classes.headingContainerMobile}>
          <p className={classes.allEventsTitleMobile}>ALL EVENTS</p>

          <div className={classes.parentDivImageMobile}>
            <div className={classes.ImageDivMobile}>
              <img
                src={EventsHeroImageMobile}
                className={classes.heroImageMobile}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>

        <section>
          <p
            className={
              events.upcomingEvent
                ? classes.upcomingShowMobileUpcomingEvent
                : classes.upcomingShowMobile
            }
          >
            UPCOMING SHOW
          </p>

          {events.upcomingEvent ? (
            <p className={classes.noUpcomingShowsMobile}>
              NO UPCOMING SHOWS...FOR NOW.
            </p>
          ) : (
            <div className={classes.flyerImageMobile}>
              <div className={classes.upcomingShowParentMobile}>
                <img
                  src={UpcomingShowFlyerMobile}
                  className={classes.imageStyleMobile}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
        </section>

        {events.upcomingEvent ? upcoming : null}
        <section>
          <h2
            className={
              events.upcomingEvent
                ? classes.pastShowsUpcomingMobile
                : classes.pastShowsMobile
            }
          >
            PAST SHOWS
          </h2>

          <div className={classes.eventsCardMobile}>
            {events.map(({ node }, i) => {
              if (node.upcomingEvent) return

              return (
                <EventCard
                  key={`${node.name}-${i}`}
                  name={node.name}
                  month={node.month}
                  day={node.day}
                  time={node.time}
                  location={node.location}
                />
              )
            })}
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>

      {/* -----------Desktop View --------------- */}
      <div className={classes.containerDesktop}>
        <div className={classes.headingContainerDesktop}>
          <Grid
            container
            direction='row'
            className={classes.gridContainerDesktop}
          >
            <Grid item md={6} lg={6}>
              <div className={classes.allEventsContainerDesktop}>
                <p className={classes.allEventsTitleDesktop}>ALL EVENTS</p>
              </div>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item md={6} lg={6} className={classes.countdownGridContainer}>
              <div>
                <div className={classes.parentDivImageDesktop}>
                  <div className={classes.ImageDivDesktop}>
                    <img
                      src={EventsHeroImage}
                      className={classes.placeHolderImageDesktop}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p className={classes.upcomingShowDesktop}>UPCOMING SHOW</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          {!events.upcomingEvent ? (
            upcoming
          ) : (
            <p className={classes.noUpcomingShowsDesktop}>
              NO UPCOMING SHOWS...FOR NOW.
            </p>
          )}
          <h2 className={classes.pastShowsDesktop}>PAST SHOWS</h2>
        </div>
        <div className={classes.eventsCardDesktop}>
          {events.map(({ node }, i) => {
            if (node.upcomingEvent) return

            return (
              <EventCard
                key={`${node.name}-${i}`}
                name={node.name}
                month={node.month}
                day={node.day}
                time={node.time}
                location={node.location}
              />
            )
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default EventsContainer
```

I was erroneously calling on events data when I should have been calling on the node itself.